# Angular2 Http not sending POST request with form data

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I posted this question twice on stackoverflow and I got some down vote by people who did not understand the problem.

**The Problem**

Moltin api requires that body data in post request sent to the route https://api.molt.in/oauth/access_token come as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` only, it does not support `application/json`, don't ask me why cause I don't know.

So I needed to send a post request with angular2 that fulfils all of that, so I used the code below.

```
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
let options = new RequestOptions({headers});

let body = {
    client_id: env.MOLTIN_CLIENT_ID,
    grant_type: 'implicit'
 }

this.http.post('https://api.molt.in/oauth/access_token', body, options)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result, 'result reached')
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err, 'error reached');
  });
```

But the above code never works, the formdata is parsed wrongly so the server returns the error

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.molt.in/oauth/access_token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

The reason why this error is thrown, is because during the preflight the browser sends an OPTIONS request which the server does not acknowledge.

I also tried stringifying the body values using `JSON.stringify(body)`, but this did not help.

**PS I have the solution that is why I am making this post so others can benefit from it, I will post it shortly below**

**Also Note: That I am using a 3rd party API and cannot modify anything there**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching through the documentation for several hours, I found `URLSearchParams` and decided to try it, lo and behold it worked.

Below is the final solution

```
 let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
 let options = new RequestOptions({headers});
 let  body = new URLSearchParams();
 body.append('client_id', env.MOLTIN_CLIENT_ID);
 body.append('grant_type', 'implicit');

this.http.post('https://api.molt.in/oauth/access_token', body.toString(), options)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result, 'result reached')
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err, 'error reached');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

@James, Actually you need to enable the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in your WebApi project. The below code you want to add it under webconfig file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you read the question well, I am using a third party API, I don't have access to it and cannot modify the API

Comment: You need to pass header along with body. So try this  this.http.post('https://api.molt.in/oauth/access_token', { headers,  body }, options)